# Having problems getting specific column in file to be printed to output file in a hash

Tags: perl, while-loop, hash

I am working on an assignment and I am having some issues getting portions of a certain file to be printed to the output file in a hash. I was given a large file containing a list of different species (along with some other variables that aren't too important) and I am getting stuck on how to isolate that specific column and put it into a hash that can be printed to the output while counting how many times each species is mentioned.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

open IN, $ARGV[0];                      ## open input file given as argument 1
open OUT, ">", $ARGV[1];                ## open output file given as argument 2
my @cols;                               ## creates variable to hold column of data


print "\nWorking on file: $ARGV[0]\n\n";        ## while data exists in input file, read 
                                                ## line by line
while (my $file = <IN>) {               
    chomp $file;                        ## remove trailing newline
    print "$file\n";
    @cols = split /\t/, $file;          ## split data into columns on tab
    print "@cols[9]\n";
    my %hits;
    $hits{species} += 1;
    print "$hits{species}\n";
    print OUT "@cols[9]\n";             ##write species column to output file
}
print "File has been read and output written!\n";


close IN;
close OUT;
```

This is currently what I have for my code and any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Sample of input data (Bacteria_firmicutes is the 11th column)

```
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_firmicutes
```

Comment: Please give us some sample data and tell us what happens when you run. My guess is that you need to declare hits **before** the while loop and  perhaps do the printing after the loop completes.

Comment: I went ahead an declared my hits before the while loop but I'm still getting the same result; when I go back to my terminal I enter- perl blast__parser.pl blastp.tsv hits_per_species.txt. blastp.tsv is the file containing all of my data and hits_per_species.txt is the output file I'm trying to use. After I enter this information into my terminal the whole file comes up but when I look in my output file it's still empty. Sorry if it ends up being a really simple solution, this course is my first time coding and none of it is really making sense to me.

Comment: Thank you -- now go "edit" the question and put a sample of the input in the question itself. Also: which column do you need? By your code it appears to be the 10th one, is it?

Comment: I just added a sample of what my input data looks like; yes I am needing the 10th column.

Comment: Thank you (but it's not clear what the columns are -- look at how it came out on the page. Is the word `Query` the first column?).

Comment: So, what is the problem?  Do you want to count how many times `Bacillus_subtilis` (is that the column of interest?), and other possible species that show up at that column, were seen in the file?  (Are those "species"?) If so, tthen on each line you do `$hits{$column[9]}++;` (that `++` is the same as `+= 1`).  That increments the number which is the value for the key which is the string at `$column{9}` (the first time a particular such species is seen the hash key is created).  Is that what you need?

Comment: i think what the problem is is the split function is using tab as a delimiter when you are actually going to need to formulate some kind of regex parser for this input. the words are seperated by spaces and the split function is splitting on tabs

Comment: `@cols[9]` should be written as `$cols[9]`. You don't need to use the array slice syntax if you're only slicing one value. `$hits{species} += 1;` should probably be `$species = $cols[9];` and then `$hits{$species} += 1;`. `$hits{species} += 1` (without the dollar sign before "species") just increases the value for the key "species" instead of increasing the value for a specific species key.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the split functions tab delimiter to split on spaces instead. I shortened the code a bit to make it a little easier to understand. On Perl 5.16.3... this works just fine.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my @cols;                               ## creates variable to hold column of data

print "\nWorking on __DATA__\n\n";

while (my $file = <DATA>) {               
    chomp $file;                        ## remove trailing newline
    print "$file\n";
    @cols = split /\s/, $file;          ## split data into columns on SPACE. OR CHANGE TO TAB DELIMITED SAMPLE DATA
    print "$cols[10]\n";
    my %hits;
    $hits{species} += 1;
}

__DATA__
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_firmicutes
```

EDIT: I would also like to submit this for you to study. you can capture the last string before the new line character. This would be useful if you wanted to always get the very last column in the sample data.

Also, using this method, you can modify the regex and search for specific patterns in sample data.

```
while (my $file = <DATA>) {               

    $file =~ /.*\s(.*)\n$/; #or $file =~ /.*(SOME_PATTERN).*\n$/
    print $1;

}

__DATA__
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_firmicutes
```

EDIT 2: Here is a good way to keep track of which and how many patterns were matched in the sample data (EDIT: code shortened some more):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
 
my %hits; #always declare hash/arrays outside of loops unless its intentional. 

# ADD and/or INCREMENT hash foreach pattern found 

$hits{$1}++ while (<DATA> =~ /.*\s(.*)\n$/);

print "$_: $hits{$_}\n", for keys %hits;

__DATA__
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_firmicutes
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_firmicutes
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_firmicutes
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test2
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test2
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test2
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test2
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test2
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test3
Query dbj|BAI87270.2| 1 456 98.048 461 911 0.0 645657 Bacillus_subtilis Bacteria_test3
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, assuming your actual input is tab separated values instead of space separated like the sample input in the question seems to be.

Here's what I changed:

- Added mode to first `open()` call
- Assigned `$cols[9]` to a variable `$species` then used that as the key for `%hits`.
- Removed the `print` calls in the while loop
- Moved declaration of `%hits` above the loop
- Added `foreach` loop that loops through `%hits` and prints the number of times that species name was seen and the species name to `*OUT` filehandle

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

open IN, "<", $ARGV[0];                 ## open input file given as argument 1
open OUT, ">", $ARGV[1];                ## open output file given as argument 2
my @cols;                               ## creates variable to hold column of data


print "\nWorking on file: $ARGV[0]\n\n";        ## while data exists in input file, read 
                                                ## line by line
my %hits;
while (my $file = <IN>) {               
    chomp $file;                        ## remove trailing newline
    print "$file\n";
    @cols = split /\t/, $file;          ## split data into columns on tab
    my $species = $cols[9];
    $hits{$species} += 1;
}
foreach my $species (keys %hits) {
    print OUT "$hits{$species} $species\n";
}
print "File has been read and output written!\n";


close IN;
close OUT;
```